# Animation of contentmode of a uiview

Tags: ios7, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to override the animation of contentmode of a uiview. How can I do that within a uiviewcontroller.
Any help will be apreciated,
Happy holidays to all.

Comment: Animatie the viewcontroller? or to present a viewController?

Comment: I'm trying to override the default duration animation of a uiview when changing from  contentmodeaspectfill to contentmodeaspectfit of a uiview.